# WebExtensions on Firefox for Android: is it possible to use some analogue of context menu?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions, firefox-android

I installed my extension on Firefox for Android and not found any analogue of the context menu. Documentation about [context menu](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/user_interface/Context_menu_items) and [development of extensions for Android](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Developing_WebExtensions_for_Firefox_for_Android) is not mention it. [The page about supported APIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Browser_support_for_JavaScript_APIs) looks like missing `contextMenus` too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The contextMenus API is now called "menus". There is no support on Android yet, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/menus

Relevant bugs:

- https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1363017 Implement contextMenus.remove WebExtension API method on android
- https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1363018 Implement contextMenus.removeAll WebExtension API method on android
- https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1363019 Implement contextMenus.update WebExtension API method on android
- https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1363020 Implement contextMenus.onClicked WebExtension API event on android
- https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1269062 [tracking] ContextMenus API support for Android WebExtensions
- https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1363016 Implement contextMenus.create WebExtension API method on android